# I am from India, with a Schengen business visa. Can I visit the UK with this visa for 3 days?

Tags: uk, schengen

I have a business Schengen visa, maximum 90 days per visit. Can I visit the UK in this period with my Schengen visa?

Answer (score 7):

No.  The UK is not part of the Schengen area, and Schengen visas are not valid for visiting the UK.  You should apply for a [standard visitor visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa).